# Chrome - Is there a way to bookmark recent history?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, history, extension

I would like to bookmark all recently visited pages, is there a way to do this?

Preferably a one click solution.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome shows the history with `chrome://history-frame/`; you can easily set a bookmark on that.

(If you want to set *multiple* bookmarks, one each for each line in the history, that is probably not possible or useful - Chrome keeps *all* the history, unless you delete it, and that would mean you have 20000 or 50000 or millions of pages in the history)